# Randomly pick a value from a set of rows and add value to new row below

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, dplyr, apply

my R skills are not sufficient to tackle this issue so I'm hoping someone can help.

My data look like this:

```
head(human.players,25)
```

| Season | Episode | Round | Player | Player_type | Crowd_size | q1_a | q2_a | q3_a | q4_a | q5_a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 2 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 6 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 1 | 2 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 7 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 7 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 7 | 3 | 1 | 2 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 2020 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | NA |
| 2020 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | NA |

Vars from q1_a:q5_a represent whether a player got the question wrong (0) or correct (1). Each player plays in a specific round (there are 7 rounds per episode). In the first 4 rounds, there are 3 players. However, in rounds 5-7, there are only 2 players (the one player that is eliminated has NA's - e.g., in episode 1, this is player 3 - see table above).

I need to create a **random player**. This means that for the first 4 rounds I need to randomly select an answer (for each of the 5 questions) from the three players within that round and add the "random player" row value. For rounds 5 to 7 I need to select an answer from the two players (ignoring the NA) and add the "random player" row value.

An algorithm of sorts would have to look at round 1 (only those rows), sample one value from the three rows, paste it into round 1 (i.e., create row 4 in this example ) and do that for each of the 5 questions. Then for round 2...

This is how it is supposed to look like where I've added player 4 - the random player:

| Season | Episode | Round | Player | Player_type | Crowd_size | q1_a | q2_a | q3_a | q4_a | q5_a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2020 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | NA |

Writing this, I'm thinking it may be impossible or at least very difficult to do this so this question is more like a "hail mary". I presume some combination of sample(), apply(), and creating a custom function is necessary, but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one pipe that samples the new players and their scores into a separate frame, which you can then `bind_rows` back into the original data.

```r
set.seed(2021)
newplayers <- dat %>%
  filter(!is.na(q1_a)) %>%
  group_by(Season, Episode, Round) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), ~ sample(., size=1)), .groups = "drop") %>%
  mutate(Player = NA_integer_, Player_type = NA_integer_)
newplayers
# # A tibble: 8 x 11
#   Season Episode Round Player Player_type Crowd_size  q1_a  q2_a  q3_a  q4_a q5_a 
#    <int>   <int> <int>  <int>       <int>      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <lgl>
# 1   2020       1     1     NA          NA          3     0     0     1     1 NA   
# 2   2020       1     2     NA          NA          3     1     1     0     0 NA   
# 3   2020       1     3     NA          NA          3     0     1     1     0 NA   
# 4   2020       1     4     NA          NA          3     0     0     1     1 NA   
# 5   2020       1     5     NA          NA          2     1     1     1     0 NA   
# 6   2020       1     6     NA          NA          2     0     0     0     0 NA   
# 7   2020       1     7     NA          NA          2     0     0     1     1 NA   
# 8   2020       2     1     NA          NA          3     0     1     0     0 NA   

bind_rows(dat, newplayers) %>%
  arrange(Season, Episode, Round, is.na(Player), Player) %>%
  head(.)
#   Season Episode Round Player Player_type Crowd_size q1_a q2_a q3_a q4_a q5_a
# 1   2020       1     1      1           1          3    0    1    0    0   NA
# 2   2020       1     1      2           1          3    0    1    1    1   NA
# 3   2020       1     1      3           1          3    0    0    0    1   NA
# 4   2020       1     1     NA          NA          3    0    0    1    1   NA
# 5   2020       1     2      1           1          3    1    1    0    1   NA
# 6   2020       1     2      2           1          3    1    0    1    0   NA
```

I didn't know what values to put into `Player*`, so I chose `NA`.

---

Data

```r
# dput(dat)
dat <- structure(list(Season = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L), Episode = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Round = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Player = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Player_type = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Crowd_size = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), q1_a = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 1L, NA, 1L, 0L, 0L), q2_a = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, 0L, NA, 1L, 0L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L), q3_a = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, NA, 0L, 0L, NA, 1L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 1L), q4_a = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, 1L, 0L), q5_a = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```